# VB.NET Cannot find files within "My Project"

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on updating an old VB.NET project, refactoring the code to use Microsoft's supported frameworks.

Right now, I can't build the project as it can't find "My Project\Resources.resx". Looking at the Solution explorer, it appears all the files under "My Project" cannot be found.

Any ideas?

[image: Solution explorer screenshot]

EDIT: I've tried searching for each missing file in file explorer and nada. I've also tried right-clicking and selecting 'Include' but that option does not appear.

Comment: Right click and 'include' ?

Comment: Did you look in File Explorer to see whether they actually exist? If they don't then you must have deleted them. This is why you should be using source control, even if you're a hobbyist. If the files are gone then they're gone. You can try to recreated them by creating a new project and copying the corresponding files from there, making any changes required in the process.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer there's no include option when right-clicking.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've searched for all the missing files in file explorer and cannot find anything.

Comment: Then the files really are missing.

Comment: If the files don't exist then they must have been deleted somehow, or not copied over from some original source. If you can't get them from such an original source then, as I said, you will have to recreate them in a new project. Create a new project and look to see exactly what files it has in that location that the old project doesn't. It's possible that you'll have to create the settings and resources files via the project properties. Look in them to see what might need to be changed, e.g. project names, etc, and then make those modifications in copies of those files.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: turns out the previous guy deleted the "My Project/" folder thinking it wasn't important hahaha.